# Add Date-Column to Checklistbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Checklistbox which contains some filenames
how do I add a column with the createdate of this file?

So the checkedListBox gets its entries from a treeview which represents a directory - tree. and each node is a subfolder.
The included files are shown in the listbox, but only by name

edit:
it is the checkListBox Control by devexpress (WinForms)
I want it do be displayed like that:

name | lastChangedDate | Size

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is totally unclear. Can you show your work and tell where you stuck exactly? Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Read the help center before start a question. It will be helpful for you and us. We can't read minds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show data in `checklistbox` like columns. Try below code -

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo (@"<Path to Folder>");
        foreach(FileInfo fi in  di.GetFiles())
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(fi.Name + " | " + fi.LastWriteTime + " | " + (fi.Length / 1024).ToString() + " KB");
```

Comment: I did, I just had to wait